# .NET JsonConverter Tuples List

Tags: c#, .net, json.net

I'm trying to use a custom JsonConverter to convert a `List<Tuple<string,string>>` to a `List<Tuple<string, JRaw>>` during serilization. So if I have a `List<Tuple<string, string>>` when I preform `JsonConvert.SerializeObject` on that list I want it to serialize that list as if it was of type `List<Tuple<string,JRaw>>`. The reason being that the `Item2` field of the Tuple is already formatted Json, so I want to wrap it in a JRaw value so it doesn't get read as a string during serialization.

Problem being the documentation on JsonConverters is kind of sparse. I've been looking at similar questions all over stack-overflow and google and can't seem to find a good tutorial on how to create JsonConverters. Any help with either this specific example or a link to a good tutorial would be awesome.

For those of your who are curious this was my first attempt:

```

```
public class DataJsonConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        List<Tuple<string, JRaw>> jlist = ((List<Tuple<string, string>>)value).Select(t => new Tuple<string, JRaw>(t.Item1, new JRaw(t.Item2))).ToList();
        new JArray(jlist).WriteTo(writer);

    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Tuple<string, string>>>(reader.ReadAsString());
    }

    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

```

This should clear up any misconceptions that I know what I am doing when it comes to writing JsonConverters. Side note, I am also new to C# as a language coming from Java.

Comment: `Any help with either this specific example or a link`, Would be good if we knew your problem..

Comment: What have you tried so far that doesn't work?  What do you get as error or unexpected output?  We can't help if we don't fully understand your issue :)

Comment: So what is your _actual_ problem? Do you get an error with your code?  Unexpected results?

Answer (score 0):

Can you show your code, without we are quite clueless to your issue and approach.

Also, could you clarify `List<Tuple<string, string>>` because that more than likely isn't a going to be viable.  Why do you need the `Tuple`?  Yes, it will store an ordered list which in theory would be redundant if you build an `object` which will store all your values.

This code would accomplish that:

*Client:*

```
function BuildOrder(Product, Quantity, Price) {
     var item = null;
     item = {
          Product: Product,
          Quantity: Quantity,
          Price: Price
     };
}
```

That will build our `object`, which will be deserialized in our example below.

```
order.push(BuildOrder(product, quantity, price)); // Fill our Array
var convert = JSON.stringfy(order); 

$.ajax({
     url: 'location to your page',
     data: { Order: convert },
     type: 'POST',

     success: function (order) {
          // Returned object, how should it apply to your page.
     }
});
```

Then on the server side code, you would have a model:

```
public class Order
{
     public string Product { get; set; }
     public string Quantity { get; set; }
     public string Price { get; set; }
}
```

Now on the page being resolved you simply would do:

```
JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
List<Order> deserialize = serializer.Deserialize<List<Order>>(order);
foreach(var content in deserialize)
{
     // Iterate through your client data sent to the server.
}
```

... After that you would send the `object` back to the client for the data. That is the premise, but without more clarification we aren't sure what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Even though there was some celerity issues in my question and some concerns in my design choices just in case someone finds that they have a similar problem to me I'll post the JsonConverter I ended up using:

```

```
public class DataJsonConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        List<Tuple<string, JRaw>> jlist = ((List<Tuple<string, string>>)value).Select(t => new Tuple<string, JRaw>(t.Item1, new JRaw(t.Item2))).ToList();
        serializer.Serialize(writer, jlist);
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        JArray jarray = JArray.Load(reader);

        List<Tuple<string, string>> result = new List<Tuple<string, string>>();
        string item1;
        string item2;
        foreach (JObject j in jarray)
        {
            item1 = j.GetValue("Item1").ToString();
            item2 = j.GetValue("Item2").ToString();
            result.Add(new Tuple<string, string>(item1, item2));
        }
        return result;
    }

    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return typeof(List<Tuple<string, string>>).IsAssignableFrom(objectType);
    }
}
```

```

NewtonSoft already knows how to write `List<Tuple<string, JRaw>>` as Json I just needed to serialize it.

I also found it helpful to visit this [Json .Net Blog post](https://json.codeplex.com/discussions/56031), as well as this [post](http://blog.maskalik.com/asp-net/json-net-implement-custom-serialization/).